# How to add a new element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a new element with jQuery with DOM-manipulation but I'm a little bit confused with all the functions like eq, nth and so on.

Here is my base construct:

```
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  Here should be the DOM-Manipulation
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where the "Here should be the DOM-Manipulation" I would like to insert a new tablerow.

Comment: Have a look . It works exactly as what you require. I have changed the answer based on your edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```js
$(".tableInput").eq(3).find('tr').append('<tr><td>Hello World..!</td></tr>');
```

```css
.tableInput{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableInput">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tableInput">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tableInput">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tableInput">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

> :eq() allows you to access the elements in the jQuery object by index

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

> :nth-child also allows you to access the an element by index, however it only applies to the term to the immediate left of it.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Just append a new table row to the last `<table>` element like this

```js
$('table:last').prev().append('<tr><td>Here is your new table row</td></tr>')
```

```css
table{
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Here should be the DOM-Manipulation !-->
</table>

<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> :eq() allows you to access the elements in the jQuery object by index

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

> :nth-child also allows you to access the an element by index, however it only applies to the term to the immediate left of it.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: table:last does not work because it is the next-to-last table in the document. Is it possible to count with nth or nth-type-of?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I've corrected my codesnippet because I've forgotten the last table element

Comment: I have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $tr = '<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>';
  $('#myTable tr:first').after($tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableInput" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add table row with following ways :
1. Via append :
  a. Without declaring element before :

```
$("#tableInput").last().append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

b. With declaring element :

```
var tableRow = $('<tr><td></td></tr>');
$("#tableInput").last().append(tableRow);
```

2. Via after :

   ```
   var tableRow = $('<tr><td></td></tr>');$("#tableInput").last().children().after(tableRow);
   ```